# Synchronizing Core Data to CloudKit Public Database

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

In the following link, there is the source code for a project that allows you to sync core data between the same user devices. Data is stored in User Private Database... is there a way to sync data from CoreData in public CloudKit database so the app will be the same between ALL app users?
Why NSPersistentCloudKitContainer doesn't allow you to set this?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/synchronizing_a_local_store_to_the_cloud

Comment: I haven't read the docs but I imagine it could be a load problem if many users were making changes to a shared db, the sync problem would be enormous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now possible in iOS 14.0+ Beta and macOS 11.0+ Beta via the new **databaseScope** property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontaineroptions/3580372-databasescope

The possible values are `.public` (the public database), `.private` (the private database) and `.shared` (the shared database).

E.g.:

```
let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "test")
guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
    fatalError("Error")
}
description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
```

The video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10650 describes how to sync the Core Data store with the CloudKit public database by setting the databaseScope value to `.public.`

You may also need an `#available` check to ensure backwards compatibility, ie:

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Comment: Yep. Seems like in addition we have to manually create indices in CloudKit dashboard for the custom entities.

Comment: Adding to @JonEasy's comment: in Cloudkit Dashboard, mark the `recordName` and `modifiedAt` indices as "queryable"

Comment: is it possible to set databaseScope for each record? Ex:

record 1 is on private, public and shared
record 2 is on private and public 
etc...

Comment: @Mane Manero did you get an answer on this question ? (.public and . private on the same store)

Answer (score 3):

To answer last question in comments, yes it is possible use .public and . private on the same store. This is the link to the project: [Messanger by Patrick Maltagliati on 10/2/20](https://github.com/patmalt/Messanger/blob/main/Messanger/Persistence/Persistence.swift#L47)

```
   init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Messanger")
    
    let defaultDesctiption = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
    let url = defaultDesctiption?.url?.deletingLastPathComponent()
    
    let privateDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url!.appendingPathComponent("private.sqlite"))
    let privateOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "iCloud.com.Maltagliati.Messanger")
    privateOptions.databaseScope = .private
    privateDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = privateOptions
    privateDescription.configuration = "Private"
    privateDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    privateDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
    
    let publicDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url!.appendingPathComponent("public.sqlite"))
    let publicOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "iCloud.com.Maltagliati.Messanger")
    publicOptions.databaseScope = .public
    publicDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = publicOptions
    publicDescription.configuration = "Public"
    publicDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    publicDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
    
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [privateDescription, publicDescription]
    
    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.forEach { $0.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null") }
    }
    
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
}
```